# Lost Internet Connection On Browsers

Tags: internet, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3 that has Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS installed, I have a repeating problem, after the computer shuts down (dead battery), or logs out I can't connect to the internet.
I will be more precise, I lost internet connection in all apps as well as the browsers, either wifi or wired, the only way I can get an indication that I'm connected is with a ping

I can ping google's DNS server 8.8.8.8.
I tried changing the DNS servers to the ones I managed to ping with no success.

Last time I had this issue I ended up reinstalling the OS.
Please help.

Comment: There has to be something more you are not saying. It can not be only the browsers not working. Think about it and please edit the question with more info.

Comment: I will be more precise, I lost internet connection in all other apps as well, either wifi or wired, the only way I can get an indication that I'm connected is with a ping

Comment: Have you tried booting from Live Media and seeing if the issue is there as well. This might rule out hardware.

Comment: I don't think its the hardware because every time I reinstall ubuntu the internet works fine, something happens that is interrupting the connection